# How to style a stackpanel inside a control template of an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to define a custom control which hosts all child elements (Buttons, in my case) in a StackPanel, where the StackPanel should apply and extend a button style

```
<ItemsControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="sharedUserControls:ButtonBarControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sharedUserControls:ButtonBarControl">
                    <StackPanel 
                        Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        IsItemsHost="True"
                        FlowDirection="{Binding Path=ButtonBarFlowDirection, ElementName=ButtonBar}">
                        <StackPanel.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogButton}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding Path=ButtonMargin, ElementName=ButtonBar}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </StackPanel.Resources>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.Resources>
```

The first part works, I can use this custom control the way I want to, but the style of the buttons is not applied in the stack panel. Why not?

I also tried

```
<ItemsControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="sharedUserControls:ButtonBarControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sharedUserControls:ButtonBarControl">
                    <StackPanel 
                        Style="{StaticResource ButtonBarStackPanel}"
                        Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        IsItemsHost="True"
                        FlowDirection="{Binding Path=ButtonBarFlowDirection, ElementName=ButtonBar}">
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.Resources>
```

And in my Styles.xaml I added

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="ButtonBarStackPanel">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogButton}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

But this gives the same results, I can't find any way to apply the desired style on the stack panels children (buttons)

Comment: It is unclear why you are doing this. Why are you not using an ItemsControl the usual way, i.e. with an ItemTemplate that defines the Button?

Comment: Not sure if it could be done simpler to be honest, I found something that does exactly what I needed in the end anyway

Answer (score 0):

Came up with the following solution where I simply specify the `ControlTemplate.Resources`

```
<ItemsControl x:Class="Common.Utilities.Git.UI.SharedUserControls.ButtonBarControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:sharedUserControls="clr-namespace:Common.Utilities.Git.UI.SharedUserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="ButtonBar">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="sharedUserControls:ButtonBarControl">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="sharedUserControls:ButtonBarControl">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogButton}">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{Binding Path=ButtonMargin, ElementName=ButtonBar}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <StackPanel 
                            Orientation="Horizontal" 
                            IsItemsHost="True"
                            FlowDirection="{Binding Path=ButtonBarFlowDirection, ElementName=ButtonBar}">
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

This allows me to use it in this way

```
    <sharedUserControls:ButtonBarControl
        ButtonMargin="5"
        ButtonBarFlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                
        <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Content="{lex:Loc Close}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}" Content="{lex:Loc OpenDocumentManagementUpdateSelectedDocumentDefinition}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding CreateNewDocumentDefinitionCommand}" Content="{lex:Loc NewDocumentDefinitionButtonText}" />
    </sharedUserControls:ButtonBarControl>
```